# How to copy javascript variable text to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm using CefSharp to build a web browser and I'm integrating some javascript on button click, etc.

I am trying to get the element by class name and then save its text to the clipboard.

It successfully finds an element and the text, but I can't set it to the clipboard no matter what.

Here is the code

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("var elems1 = document.getElementsByClassName('question-text')");
        CurBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("textt = elems1[elems1.length - 1].innerText");
        CurBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("navigator.clipboard.writeText(textt);");
}
```

It says that the document is not focused, but I tried to focus it using

```
textt.focus();
```

or

```
elems1.focus():
```

it returns "textt.focus(); is not a function" or "elems1.focus(): is not a function"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, they are using "function copyToClipboard(text)" etc, But I need it inside  "CurBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync"

Comment: Is that impossible? `CurBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("function copyToClipboard(text) { ... function content here ... }")`

Comment: Can you write it for my code if it's possible? I don't know how to do that

Comment: Why can't you get text and set it to clipboard? Why do you need such a convoluted JavaScript solution for it? (assuming post is not marked C# by mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running everything in on

```
CurBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("const element = document.createElement('textarea'); element.value = document.getElementsByClassName('question-text')[0].innerText; document.body.appendChild(element); element.select(); document.execCommand('copy'); document.body.removeChild(element);");
```

If it still doesn't say its in focus, try adding the focus within that too.

Comment: the document is not in focus again and textt.focus is not a function

Comment: Right try it with `elems1[0].focus()` (or the index you specifically want) or do `document.getElementById("idName").focus();` You might have more than one element with that class so it makes elems1 an array.

Comment: It doesn't have an Id, only Class... Can you edit your answer with that?

Comment: No worries, try doing what I just added. I went off of the index provided assuming you wish to copy the last index that you stated in the original code.

Comment: Tried it, "Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Document is not focused."

Comment: Interesting, could you log what elems1 gives you?

Comment: Thank you! You deserve a lot of reputation here!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to message me whenever!